# Tried to synchronously call function from a different thread

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

When I try to formate date using dayjs or when I try to format currency using Intl.NumberFormat()
I've got the following error

Code sample

[image]

[image]

Could anyone help with this?